# How do I reference a site by ID using IIS7 APPCMD?

Tags: iis, iis-7, appcmd

I know how to reference a site by name to stop and start it? For example:

```
appcmd stop site /site.name:"Microsoft SharePoint Administration"
```

How do I reference a site using its IIS ID? I tried these variations:

```
appcmd start stop /site.id:2
appcmd start stop /site.id:"2"
appcmd start stop /site.id:2
appcmd start site /section:sites /[id='2']
```

However they all return the following error:

> `ERROR ( message:Must specify the SITE object with identifier. )`

Comment: I did ask this on ServerFault but it's one of those kinda cross over questions (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3823).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doesn't look like it is supported. You can supply site name or URL but not site ID.

C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv>appcmd stop site /?
Stop virtual site

APPCMD stop SITE  <-parameter1:value1 ...>

Stops the specified virtual site, and prevents new requests from being
received on its binding endpoints. The exact site identifier must be provided
and must resolve to an existing site.

Supported parameters:

identifier (required)

```
Site name or url of the site to stop
```

/site.name

```
Site name or url of the site to stop (same as identifier)
```

Comment: Yep...looks like ID isn't support. Going to hold out a bit longer though.

Answer (score 2):

Work for me, but it isn't perfect:

Id website = 169

```
%systemroot%\system32\inetsrv\APPCMD list sites /xml | find "169"
```